# Execute Oracle RAC cluster commands via Solaris RBAC?

Tags: oracle, solaris, rbac

Executing [Oracle RAC](http://www.oracle.com/database/rac_home.html) cluster management commands such as `$ORA_CRS_HOME/bin/crs_start` requires root permissions.

Using [Solaris RBAC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-4557/rbac-1.html#scrolltoc) (Role-Based Access Control), one can give a non-`root` user permissions to execute those commands, but the commands still fail internally. Example:

```
$pfexec /opt/11.1.0/crs/bin/crs_stop SomeArg
CRS-0259: Owner of the resource does not belong to the group.
```

Is there a complete RBAC solution for Oracle RAC or does the executor **need** to be `root`?

**EDIT:** Note that my original `/etc/security/exec_attr` contained:

```
MyProfile:suser:cmd:::/opt/11.1.0/crs/bin/crs_start:uid=0
MyProfile:suser:cmd:::/opt/11.1.0/crs/bin/crs_start.bin:uid=0
```

As [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195967/martin) suggests below, this needed to be changed to add `gid=0` as:

```
MyProfile:suser:cmd:::/opt/11.1.0/crs/bin/crs_start:uid=0;gid=0
MyProfile:suser:cmd:::/opt/11.1.0/crs/bin/crs_start.bin:uid=0;gid=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error (you need to add the exec_attr line to the question), you probably just set the `uid`, while the command seems to require the `gid` to be set too.

Comment: Yes yes! Great job answering my question even though I didn't quite provide enough info (sorry!) :-P